# Create an alias in bash when exiting a python script

Tags: python, bash, alias

I have written a shell in python (using the cmd module) and when using this shell, certain information about commands run ect. is outputted to a text file.  I would like to write a piece of code that creates an alias to view the text file in my bash shell (eg as if I had executed the following command:
`alias latest.trc='less <path to file>`
My best current effort is:

```
x="alias %s = 'less %s'" % (<alias name>, <path>)
y=shlex.split(x)
atexit.register(subprocess.call, y)
```

This works to execute some commands on exit, eg if x="echo 'bye'" but I get the error

```
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

The path I am entering is certainly valid and if I run x directly from the command line it works.

Any help either with why my code is hitting an error or a better way to achieve the same effect would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You get an error because `alias` is a `bash` command, not an executable. You must run `subprocess.call` inside a `shell`:

```
import subprocess                                                              
import atexit                                                                  
import shlex                                                                   

x="alias %s = 'less %s'" % ('a', 'whatever')                                   
y=shlex.split(x)                                                               
atexit.register(lambda args: subprocess.call(args, shell=True), y)
```

But, given the fact that subprocess spawns a new process, whatever changes are made to the environment it runs into, are lost on exit.

You'd better instead create a file where you put all these aliases and source it by hand when you need to use them.